# C# serial port missing answer

Tags: c#, serial-port

I made a code to send a message and get the answer asynchronously using a serial port

```c#
class Foo
{
   SerialPort port;
   private List<byte> RxedData;

   public Foo(SerialPort sp)
   {
      sp.DataReceived += Data_Rx;
      port = sp;
   }

   public bool Send(in byte[] tx, int rx, int timeout_ms = 100, int retry = 0)
   {
      AsyncPortFlush();
      port.Write(tx, 0, tx.Length);
      while (!AsyncPortRead(timeout_ms, rx))
      {
         if(retry --> 0)
         {
            AsyncPortFlush();
            port.Write(tx, 0, tx.Length);
         }
         else return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   private bool AsyncPortRead(int timeout_ms, int nbOfBytes)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(timeout_ms);
      return RxedData.Count >= nbOfBytes;
   }

   private void AsyncPortFlush()
   {
      if (RxedData == null) RxedData = new List<byte>();
      else RxedData.Clear();
   }

   private void Data_Rx(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (sender is SerialPort self && self.IsOpen)
         while (self.BytesToRead > 0) RxedData.Add((byte)self.ReadByte());
   }
}
```

My issue is that sometimes I miss completely the answer, I checked hardware wise with a logic analyzer and I do get the answer, I still need to check if it gets to windows with wireshark but I suppose there no issue on this side

Do you have any idea why I'm missing the answer ?

Comment: `if(retry --> 0)` will always be false if the `retry` argument is 0. Maybe that causes your issue.

Comment: Maybe this helps: and if it's only to find another person that suffers from it ... https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: The DataReceived event runs on a threadpool thread, List<> is not thread-safe.  There's just no point in using DataReceived when you're going to wait for a response, just call SerialPort.Read() directly.  Don't call Thread.Sleep either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard there are sometimes issues with the `DataReceived` event. As Hans Passant stated in his comment, the event is invoked on another thread and probably you have some issues because your list is not thread-safe. Maybe you can try to write your code without the event?

```
private bool AsyncPortRead(int timeout_ms, int nbOfBytes)
   {
      try
      {
         port.ReadTimeout = timeout_ms;
         byte[] data = new byte[nbOfBytes];
         int receivedBytes = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
         return receivedBytes  == nbOfBytes;
      }
      catch (TimeoutException)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: just add parenthesis around TimeoutException